# Spring Social Twitter - Exclude retweets

Tags: spring, spring-social-twitter

Is there a way in Spring Social Twitter to search for tweets but exclude retweets? Currently I use the `search` method like this but I finds - of course - also retweeted tweets.

```
twitter.searchOperations().search('stackoverflow', 100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to the [Twitters API 1.1](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets) it's currently not possible to exclude retweets when searching for tweets. Nevertheless I have overlook Spring model class `org.springframework.social.twitter.api.Tweet` for a [tweet](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-twitter/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/social/twitter/api/Tweet.html). The is a property `retweet` on that class that can be use to filter the result.

Answer (score 2):

May be little late to answer, but its actually now possible to filter out the retweets from search results.

```
  "puppy -filter:retweets"  containing “puppy”, filtering out retweets
```

So, in above case with Spring Social, you can just change the query to

```
  twitter.searchOperations().search('stackoverflow -filter:retweets', 100)
```

This would return all tweets containing `stackoverflow`, and filter out retweets.

You can check all [search operators](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/standard-operators) for standard(Free) API.